# Shadertoy getting help moving to glsl

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

I spent some time writing a shader on shadertoy but now, when I try to translate my code to opengl I don't know how to calculate the `uv` that they describe as like this:

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
```

How can I do that in a typical opengl 330 core fragment shader?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Use [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) and pass a uniform variable for `iResolution`.
   Everything else will work exactly like in your ShaderToy code.
2. Pass texture coordinates from the vertex shader: Every vertex shader needs to output `gl_Position` and `gl_Position.xy / gl_Position.w` is defined to be a pair of screen coordinates ranging from -1 to 1. That means that you can easily compute "screen texture coordinates" from that in your vertex shader and pass it to the fragment shader like this:
   `uv = (gl_Position.xy / gl_Position.w) * 0.5 + vec2(0.5)`.
   Note that `gl_Position.w` is 1 for the typical ShaderToy scenario, since you likely want to render a flat, screen filling triangle/quad that does not have any "perspective properties".

If you do not need the resolution somewhere else, I would recommend the second solution: Both solutions pass data per fragment, but only the first solution need to pass a uniform (which requires some more CPU side code).